# How to connect GitHub API using console application and oAuth

Tags: github, oauth, github-api

I have windows console application that needs to interact with GitHub API using [octokit.net](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/blob/master/docs/oauth-flow.md). The first step is to register application with GitHub. On the registration page i have to provide `Homepage Url` and `Authorization callback Url`

For console application what would be the values for these two fields? I really dont want to connect GitHub using userid, password

Comment: All the instructions appear to be in the link you provided

Comment: There's even a demo you can download

Comment: @twoleggedhorse   The instructions are for Asp.net...and I know how to configure if client application is a web site. However my client application is Windows Console Application.

Comment: Can you just use a personal access token?